# Tricky multiple choice question about the properties of $\int_0^x\cos x\ e^{kx^4}\ \mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

**The question**

> Let
>   $$F(x) = \int_0^x\cos x\ e^{kx^4}\ \mathrm dt,$$
>   with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Which of the following is **FALSE**?
>
> a) $F$ does not have a horizontal asymptote for $k = 3$.
>   b) $F$ is increasing for $k = -3$.
>   c) $F$ is decreasing for $k = -3$.
>   d) $F$ diverges for $k = 3$.
>   e) $F$ is odd for $k = -3$.

**My reasoning**
We can evaluate the integral:
$$F(x) = \cos x\ e^{kx^4}\int_0^x\mathrm dt = \cos x\ e^{kx^4}\big[t\big]_0^x = x\cos x\ e^{kx^4}$$

Now, $F$ is clearly an odd function (for every $k$), so e) is true.
Then we have that
$$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}F(x) = \begin{cases}\pm\infty&\qquad k > 0\\
0&\qquad k < 0
\end{cases}$$

It follows that a) and d) are true. The two remaining are both *false*: $F$, for $k = -3$, is neither increasing nor decreasing:
[image: Plot for k = -3]

I don't know what to make of it... Where lies my error?

Comment: Could it be that $\cos x\, e^{kx^4}$ inside the integral should actually be $\cos t\, e^{kt^4}$ ?

Comment: @MartinR: Well that's what I thought initially. But then I cannot evaluate the integral and I have to resort to inspection. I've analyzed that case too, and it appears to me that, again, $F$ is neither increasing nor decreasing. Any suggestions about that case?

Comment: @MartinR: What would be the correct answer in that case? I cannot work it out.

Comment: You are right that $F$ would be neither increasing nor decreasing in that case. It would be good to know if your formula is correct or not, we cannot guess it.